# SAS Rows/Columns Not Appearing (Table Formatting Issue)

Tags: formatting, sas, format

I have a data table with columns: Year, Month, Sales. It is effectively a summary table, like a pivot table in excel.

With this table, if there are no sales reported for one month (i.e. Not 0 sales, but no mention of sales so SAS cannot pinpoint a value to a certain month) then that whole row would disappear.

I do not want this to happen, I would instead like that row to display 0 rather than not appear. Is there a way to change the format of this to ensure every row would appear?

Note: The months are not calendar months, as such you could have month60 relating to 2011.

Comment: Can you tell us how the table was created? You need to describe where to find or how to determine all possible months.

Comment: It came from a big table which had every sale completed, the date of the sale and value of the sale. The dates were then grouped by year, and by month and the sales were tallied up. So if there are no sales in a particular month, then that month would not appear in this summary table (mentioned above). The only solution I can think of is adding dummy data with 0 sales so that it would fall in each of the months (and years) and force them to show up.

Comment: The reason the months can go beyond 12 is that the sale could officially start in 2011 but actually get completed in 2016, i.e. 60 months later. Although I'm not sure this is too helpful in coming up with a solution

Comment: Sounds as though you could do with separate columns for sale start date and sale completion date and perhaps summarise separately by each of those.

Answer (score 2):

If the table is being created using `proc summary` or `proc means`, one way of achieving the sort of output you want provided that you have at least 1 row for each month in your data is to use the `completetypes` option, e.g.

```
proc summary data = sashelp.class completetypes;
 class sex age;
 var weight;
 output out = mysummary mean=;
run;
```

This produces a row with frequency 0 for Sex = F, Age = 16 rather than skipping that output entirely.

A more reliable but more labour-intensive method, which works even if some values never appear anywhere in your data, is to use the `classdata` option, e.g.

```
data myclassdata;
  do SEX = 'M','F';
    do AGE = 13 to 17;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

proc summary nway data = sashelp.class classdata=myclassdata exclusive;
 class sex age;
 var weight;
 output out = mysummary2 mean=;
run;
```

The `exclusive` option here restricts the output to combinations of levels that are present in the `classdata` dataset. Without it, you get at least those specified in the classdata plus rows for all possible combinations based on observed 1-way values as though you had specified `completetypes`.

Comment: I would require the last method (for where they never actually appear in my data). However, at the start the user can define macro variables (e.g. %let ReportBasis = Year which then flows through the rest of the code to prevent manual changes to the code) as to whether they would like to see the sales by month or by year or by quarter. These macro variables would thus change the layout of the table depending on what is selected. Can this second option be adapted to be more dynamic?

Comment: And macro variables didn't seem to work in the proc summary. At the moment it is just a proc sql which selects the variables (some of which are macro) from the big table and then groups them.

Comment: Macro variables can be used to generate any code you like, if used correctly. Please post a separate question with a full reproducible example your proc summary code if you want to ask for help with that.